# Prove that this is a norm, infimum norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove that given a vector space $X$ of finite dimension, $U \subset X$ an open subset, bounded, convex and symmetric with respect to $\bar{0} \in X$ (that is if $x \in U \Rightarrow -x \in U$). Prove that

$|x|_{u} = inf \{ \lambda > 0$ | $\lambda^{-1} x \in U \}$

is a norm in X.

I prove the first two properties and only the triangular inequality remains. The problem has many parts, so I do not think that all hypotheses are necessary for this part.

I say "infimum norm" but I don't know it's name. If it does have a name, I would be grateful if you could tell me the name.

Comment: I'm an not sure how to interpret the notation you use. Do you mean to write $$ |x|_u = \inf \, \left\{ \lambda > 0 \mid \lambda^{-1}x \in U \right\}?$$

Comment: This is called the Minkowski functional of $U$ and you can easily find  a proof of triangle inequality on Wikipedia.

Comment: The triangle inequality is where you use the hypothesis that $U$ is convex. I assume you have not used that for the other properties of norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 1 {\lambda +\mu} (x+y) =\frac {\lambda} {\lambda +\mu} \frac 1 {\lambda }x+ \frac {\mu} {\lambda +\mu} \frac 1 {\mu }y \in U$ whenever $ \frac 1 {\lambda }x \in U$ and $ \frac 1 {\mu }y \in U$. Can you complete the proof of triangle inequality, given this information?

Comment: I see, $ |x+y|_{u} \leq \lambda + \mu $, particularly $ |x+y|_{u} \leq ( |x|_{u} + \epsilon / 2) + ( |y|_{u} + \epsilon / 2) $ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then we get the inequality. A lot of thanks!